# CASE statement in Python based on Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I have a data frame like this:

```
FileName  
01011RT0TU7  
11041NT4TU8  
51391RST0U2  
01011645RT0TU9  
11311455TX0TU8  
51041545ST3TU9
```

What I want is another column in the DataFrame like this:

```
FileName      |RdwyId  
01011RT0TU7   |01011000  
11041NT4TU8   |11041000  
51391RST0U2   |51391000  
01011645RT0TU9|01011645   
11311455TX0TU8|11311455    
51041545ST3TU9|51041545
```

Essentially, if the first 5 characters are digits then concat with "000", if the first 8 characters are digits then simply move them to the RdwyId column

I am noob so I have been playing with this:
Test 1:

```
rdwyre1=re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d\d')  
rdwyre2=re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d')  
rdwy1=rdwyre1.findall(str(thous["FileName"]))  
rdwy2=rdwyre2.findall(str(thous["FileName"]))  
thous["RdwyId"]=re.sub(r'\d\d\d\d\d', str(thous["FileName"].loc[:4])+"000",thous["FileName"])
```

Test 2:

```
thous["RdwyId"]=np.select(  
    [  
        re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d',thous["FileName"])!="None",  
        rdwyre2.findall(str(thous["FileName"]))!="None"  

    ],  
    [  
        rdwyre1.findall(str(thous["FileName"]))+"000",  
        rdwyre2.findall(str(thous["FileName"])),  
    ],  
    default="Unknown"  
)
```

Test 3:

```
thous=thous.assign(RdwyID=lambda x: str(rdwyre1.search(x).group())+"000" if bool(rdwyre1.search(x))==True else str(rdwyre2.search(x).group()))
```

None of the above have worked. Could anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong? and how to fix it?

Comment: are there any other types than the 5 or 8 characters?

Comment: @ombk nope. Those are the only 2 conditions

Comment: i will post a very naive method if it doesnt help let me know to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), which replicates `CASE WHEN` for multiple conditions, and Pandas' [str.isnumeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) method:

```
cond1 = df.FileName.str[:8].str.isnumeric() # first condition
choice1 = df.FileName.str[:8] # result if first condition is met
cond2 = df.FileName.str[:5].str.isnumeric() # second condition
choice2 = df.FileName.str[:5] + "000" # result if second condition is met

condlist = [cond1, cond2]
choicelist = [choice1, choice2]

df.loc[:, "RdwyId"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

df

    FileName         RdwyId
0   01011RT0TU7     01011000
1   11041NT4TU8     11041000
2   51391RST0U2     51391000
3   01011645RT0TU9  01011645
4   11311455TX0TU8  11311455
5   51041545ST3TU9  51041545
```

Comment: I get the following error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`

Comment: did you prefix it with `str`? note the way I wrote the code with the `str` :  `df.FileName.str[:8].str.isnumeric()`

Answer (score 1):

```
def filt(list1):
    for i in list1:
        if i[:8].isdigit():
            print(i[:8])
        else:
            print(i[:5]+"000")
# output

01011000
11041000
51391000
01011645
11311455
51041545
```

I mean, if your case is very specific, you can tweak it and apply it to your dataframe.

To a *dataframe*.

```
def filt(i):
    if i[:8].isdigit():
        return i[:8]
    else:
        return i[:5]+"000"
d = pd.DataFrame({"names": list_1})
d["filtered"] = d.names.apply(lambda x: filt(x)) #.apply(filt) also works im used to lambdas

#output

    names           filtered
0   01011RT0TU7     01011000
1   11041NT4TU8     11041000
2   51391RST0U2     51391000
3   01011645RT0TU9  01011645
4   11311455TX0TU8  11311455
5   51041545ST3TU9  51041545
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```py
c1 = re.compile(r'\d{5}')  
c2 = re.compile(r'\d{8}')
rdwyId = []
for f in thous['FileName']:
    m = re.match(c2, f)
    if m:
        rdwyId.append(m[0])
        continue
    m = re.match(c1, f)
    if m:
        rdwyId.append(m[0] + "000")        
thous['RdwyId'] = rdwyId
```

Edit: replaced re.search with re.match as it's more efficient, since we are only looking for matches at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `findall` with `ljust`

```
df['new'] = df.FileName.str.findall(r"(\d+)[A-z]").str[0].str.ljust(8,'0')
Out[226]: 
0    01011000
1    11041000
2    51391000
3    01011645
4    11311455
5    51041545
Name: FileName, dtype: object
```